# Solve hyperbolic PDE: $u_{xy}+u_{yy}=0$, $u(x,0)=x^5$, $u(0,y)=y^3$

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

I have to solve:

$u_{xy}+u_{yy}=0$,

where

$u(x,0)=x^5  \quad u(0,y)=y^3$

Doing the discriminant I see that $\Delta=1>0$, so it is hyperbolic but I get only one characteristic curve (because the term that accompanies $u_{xx}$ is zero).

I don't know how to solve it, could you help me?

Comment: Integrate with respect to $y$, then solve the corresponding first order PDE using method of characteristics or any other method.

Answer (score 2):

$$u_{xy}+u_{yy}=(u_x+u_y)_y=0$$
$$u_x+u_y=f(x)$$
Let $\quad u(x,y)=v(x,y)+\int f(x)dx\quad$ with arbitrary functions $f(x)$.

$$v_x+v_y=0$$
$$v(x,y)=\Phi(y-x)$$

$$u(x,y)=\Phi(y-x)+F(x)$$
with arbitrary functions $F$ and $\Phi$.

Condition : $\quad u(0,y)=y^3=\Phi(y)+F(0)$
$$\Phi(X)=X^3-F(0)\quad\text{any }X\quad\implies\quad\Phi(y-x)=(y-x)^3-F(0) $$
$$u(x,y)=(y-x)^3-F(0)+F(x)$$

Condition :$\quad u(x,0)=x^5=(-x)^3-F(0)+F(x)\quad\implies\quad F(x)=x^5+x^3+F(0)$

$u(x,y)=(y-x)^3-F(0)+x^5+x^3+F(0)$
$$u(x,y)=(y-x)^3+x^5+x^3$$